# Why does "cat ttyUSB0" not produce output?

Tags: files, usb, devices, cat, input

I connected an infrared receiver to a USB port ... (the last line of dmesg tells device file)

```
$ dmesg
[10496.596063] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[10496.751112] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0df7, idProduct=0620
[10496.751117] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[10496.751120] usb 7-2: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[10496.751124] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[10496.787441] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[10496.787467] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[10496.787483] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[10496.795104] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[10496.795129] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[10496.795160] pl2303 7-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[10496.807238] usb 7-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Then I went on to try it ...

```
$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but no output, simply hangs. Even though, as I press any button on my remote control, the infrared receiver device's LED flashes, so that does seem to work.

Why could that be?

---

notes:

- the above command quits when I remove device from USB port and prints "cat: ttyUSB0: No such device", and dmesg prints 3 lines:

  ```
   [13707.264086] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, device number 2 
   [13707.264894] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
   [13707.264915] pl2303 7-2:1.0: device disconnected)
  ```
- with the device files for keyboard this works, eg:

  ```
   $ sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-USB_USB_Keykoard-event-kbd
  ```

  produces many weird characters on the console as I press any key the keyboard
- same happens on other USB ports too

Comment: try `stty raw -echo < /dev/ttyUSB0; cat -vte /dev/ttyUSB0` instead.

Comment: @ Stephane Chazelas : similarly nothing happens

Comment: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/LIRC

Comment: If you're not getting any output then I'd suspect its a driver issue or that the hardware wasn't being correctly detected/identified. This might prove helpful too: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lirc_USB-UIRT

Comment: Please note that using infrared transceivers with USB-to-serial-bridges usually won't work.

Comment: `pl2303` is a generic USB-to-serial converter chip. The actual IR receiver is "behind" the converter chip as viewed from the computer. Serial ports are so old technology that they are not necessary plug-and-play: you would need to *know* the serial port communication parameters used by the IR receiver, and would need to configure the converter chip to use those parameters. Then the IR receiver chip might need something else to "enable" it: perhaps the activation of a particular serial handshaking signal. We would need to know the make and model of the IR receiver to find out more about it.

Answer (score 5):

I think for serial devices you have to set the baud rate before they do anything.  I'm not sure how to do that from the command line in order to get `cat` to work, but you could use a terminal emulator which takes care of it.

Try `minicom` or `screen` (i.e. `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` - replace 115200 with the baud rate of your IR receiver.)

Answer (score 3):

This may not help, but here's a similar problem I've had in the past. When I cat the device file for my mouse directly (i.e., using `cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-<mymouse>`) I get output similar to what you get with your keyboard (i.e., gibberish). However, some mouse motions, like left click, don't generate any printable characters, so the terminal shows nothing.

Of course, the mouse is still doing something, we just can't see it by `cat`'ing the device file. Fortunately the kernel has a neat feature called usbmon that is helpful for eavesdropping on the raw binary output of usb devices. Using that, we can see exactly what's happening when we perform (say) a left-click, whereas doing the same thing via `/dev` often shows nothing.

Again, this may not help, but here's how to use usbmon:

1. Make sure your kernel has usbmon enabled. The output of:
   `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep USB_MON`
   should have either `=m` or `=y` in it.
2. If it was `=m`, then load the module with `sudo modprobe usbmon`
3. To make sure all the usb sockets are showing up in the right place, run:
   `ls /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon`
   You should see something like:
   `0s  0u  1s  1t  1u  2s  2t  2u  3s  3t  3u  4s  4t  4u`

The different numbers refer to different USB ports, and the ones with a 0 in front give the aggregated output of all USB ports. So for example, running `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u` shows exactly what the device is doing, even in cases where `cat`'ing the file in `/dev` showed nothing.

Whether this solves your problem or not, it may be helpful in the future, since it's often a more helpful way to eavesdrop on USB devices than `/dev`.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue

On the other side, my device was only sending a stream of data without end-of-line

You need to set /dev/ttyUSB0 as raw to have it process stream one byte at a time:

stty -F dev/ttyUSB0 raw

(of course, make sure to set the speed properly, just add the baud value at the end of that line)

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the answer about need to initiate USB connection - it's already been initiated when you plugged in the device.

If you just want to check if it's working, use `dd if=/dev/ttyUSB0`. 
If you want to actually read those characters, you need serial terminal. Use `minicom` (CLI, need manual), `picocom` (might figure it out on your own), `cutecom` (nice graphical interface, easy) or `screen` (CLI, but really easy). You'll need to know the baudrate.. 90% it's either 115200 or 9600, might as well be 57600, 38400 or 19200.

By the way, what kind of receiver are you using? Could you give us a link to a product page or description?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the baudrate too low. Output did appear once I reconfigured the system (device and port) to use 300 instead of 150.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to recall that USB is a protocol that requires the computer to initiate the communication. It's not allowed to speak on its own. So the driver actually talks into the raw device and then captures the output. However, that's only a hunch, I'll also wait for another answer to confirm my suspitions.

Comment: But this is a question about a serial port. The fact that the serial port is connected with USB is neither here nor there.