# reading /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, tty

I'm trying to see the output of an accelerometer with Ubuntu (15.04), kernel 3.19.
The UART driver is `cp210x.ko`, and the chip of the accelerometer is MPU6050w.
So, when I plug the device, I have this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light

$ sudo dmesg -c
[45550.171578] usb 1-14.3: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
[45550.277334] usb 1-14.3: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[45550.277337] usb 1-14.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[45550.277338] usb 1-14.3: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[45550.277339] usb 1-14.3: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[45550.277340] usb 1-14.3: SerialNumber: 0001
[45550.278356] cp210x 1-14.3:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[45550.279845] usb 1-14.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0

$ lsmod | grep cp210
cp210x                 24576  1 
usbserial              49152  3 cp210x
```

The problem is when I want to read the output of `/dev/ttyUSB0`, there's nothing.
I have tried a lot of tools, cutecom, minicom, screen...
And no signs but the LED of the card which flash when I turn the card.

Here are others infos I have:

```
$ sudo lsusb -D /dev/ttyUSB0
Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0

$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 mai    4 10:57 /dev/ttyUSB0

$ stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^H; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 100; time = 2;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Could someone help me to solve this? I've seen this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120992/why-does-cat-ttyusb0-not-produce-output) but no solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

When working with `ttyUSB`, it is necessary to adjust the speed of the converter to the one with which the device is working behind the USB <-> UART converter. For example, to view information that comes from the device behind the converter, you can use a command of the form:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

where `115200` is the baudrate of the device behind the converter.

You can use the utility PuTTY and the like.

Comment: To exit screen session you should use "Ctrl+a" then "k"

Answer (score 1):

This [accelerometer](http://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-MWC-ATMega328p-MPU6050w-USB-6-Axis-Gyro-accelerometer-Control-Sensor/1688063076.html?recommendVersion=1) is in fact a "specialized" Arduino card, I didn't know !

So I just had to program it (with the Arduino software) and choose the example "DigitalReadSerial".

So now I have

```
$ tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0
���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

More info [here](http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1764146) (if it can help someone)

Answer (score -2):

1) The syntax is tail -f < /dev/ttyUSB0

2) What code did you deploy on the arduino board? I have the same board and I used http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050